# Characterizing coding with automorphisms

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am attempting the following exercise from chapter 5 of Van den Dries' notes "Introduction to Model-Theoretic Stability". I suspect the exercise shouldn't be too difficult but I've become pretty stuck. Here, $\mathbb{M}$ is a monster model ($\kappa$-saturated and strongly $\kappa$-homogeneous for some $\kappa$) in some  many-sorted language $L$.

Let $Y \subseteq \mathbb{M}_y$ with finite $y$ be definable and let $c$ be a finite tuple. Show: $c$ codes $Y$ if and only if for all $f \in Aut(\mathbb{M})$, $f(Y) = Y \iff f(c) = c$.

I can show "If $c$ codes $Y$ then for all $f \in Aut(\mathbb{M})$, $f(Y) = Y \iff f(c) = c$." with no difficulty. For the other direction I am stuck.

Assuming "for all $f \in Aut(\mathbb{M})$, $f(Y) = Y \iff f(c) = c$", I want to produce a formula $\phi(y,z)$ with no parameters such that $Y = \phi(\mathbb{M}_y, c)$ and $c$ is the unique element of our model with this property, but I can't see how to get such a formula from the condition on automorphisms. I can prove that $Y$ is definable from $c$.

Comment: 1. You haven't defined "$c$ codes $Y$", but it seems from context that the definition is: $c$ codes $Y$ if there is a formula $\varphi(y,z)$ such that $Y = \varphi(\mathbb{M}_y,c)$ and $c$ is the unique element with this property. Is that correct? (Personally, I would take $f(Y) = Y \leftrightarrow f(c) = c$ as the *definition* of $c$ codes $Y$)

Comment: 2. You write "I can show that... $c$ is definable from $Y$". Really? How do you show that?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. My working definition of "$c$ codes $Y$" is that there is a formula $\phi(x, y)$ such that $Y = \phi(\mathbb{M}, c)$ and $Y \neq \phi(\mathbb{M}, c')$ for any $c' \neq c$.

Comment: To show the other direction, suppose the condition in my last comment holds. If $f(c)\neq c$, then $f(Y) = \phi(y, f(c)) \neq \phi(y, c) = Y$. Conversely, if $f(c) = c$, then $f(Y) = \phi(y, f(c)) = \phi(y, c) = Y$.

Comment: 1. Thanks for clarifying. 2. Doesn't "$c$ is definable from $Y$" mean there are parameters $a$ from $Y$ and a formula $\theta(x,z)$ such that $c$ is the unique element of $\mathbb{M}$ satisfying $\theta(a,z)$? You haven't shown that this follows from the condition on automorphisms (in fact, it doesn't follow).

Comment: Maybe you're trying to use the theorem that if $A$ is a *small* set (size $<\kappa$) from $\mathbb{M}$ and every automorphism which fixes $A$ *pointwise* also fixes $c$, then $c$ is definable from $A$. But $Y$ is a definable set, so it's not small (unless it's finite), and the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: You're right, I missed this point. Thanks for pointing this out. I'll edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that for all $f\in\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{M})$, $f(Y) = Y \iff f(c) = c$. You've noted in the question that this implies $Y$ is definable from $c$, so let $\psi(y,z)$ be a formula such that $Y = \psi(\mathbb{M},c)$.

Let $p(z) = \mathrm{tp}(c/\varnothing)$. Then $p(z)\cup p(z') \cup \{z\neq z', \forall y\, \psi(y,z) \leftrightarrow \psi(y,z')\}$ is inconsistent (do you see why?). By compactness there is a formula $\theta(z)\in p(z)$ such that $\theta(z)\land \theta(z') \land (z\neq z') \land (\forall y\, \psi(y,z) \leftrightarrow \psi(y,z'))$ is inconsistent. Let $\varphi(y,z)$ be $\theta(z)\land \psi(y,z)$, and check that $c$ is the unique element of $\mathbb{M}$ such that $Y = \varphi(\mathbb{M},c)$.

Comment: I don't see why the set of formulas you wrote down is inconsistent, because it seems that $(c,c)$ satisfies them. Should there be an extra condition that $z \neq z'$? In that case, I believe I see why this would hold. Given a pair $(c, c')$ satisfying these, we have $tp(c / \emptyset) = tp (c' / \emptyset)$, but then we could find an automorphism $f$ which sends $c$ to $c'$. But then $f$ cannot fix $Y$, which gives us a contradiction.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include $z\neq z'$. Somehow I always go briefly crazy and forget that distinct variables can refer to distinct elements when I'm writing down first-order formulas...

Comment: I understand the solution now, thanks for the answer, and your helpful corrections!